# Ubuntu software Center freezes when opened

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I have a problem with the software center in Ubuntu Precise. Each time I open it, the software center freezes and I cannot work anymore with it (Ubuntu itself continue working without problem, its only the software center)

I usually to work with the terminal, but I'd like to know if there is any solution for this 'freezing' problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: In case other people have this problem (or something that looks like it), [the answers here might help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313117/software-center-freezing-on-start-up).

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run this command below, Check by reopening Software center:

```
sudo update-software-center
```

This will regenerate cache needed by software center.

Hope this helps.