# Software center freezing on start up

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I already did the `apt-get purge`, install and update thing but it still freezes when trying to start. This is what I get trying to start in terminal:

```
cliff@cliff-Aspire-X1301:~$ software-center
2013-06-26 17:00:29,092 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-06-26 17:00:29,097 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-06-26 17:00:29,501 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-06-26 17:00:29,653 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
Killed
```

Comment: Is the system up to date?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. For me removing the cache at `~/.cache/software-center` and then opening the Software Center, did the job.
Just open your home folder, press `ctrl`+`h` to reveal hidden files, open `.cache` and delete the folder `software-center` (or, safer, rename it, e.g. to `software-centerDeleted`). It seems no root permissions are required.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you expand this with information about how you removed it? For example, did you do it in Nautilus, after pressing Ctrl+H to show the `.cache` folder? I do think this does count as a separate answer from [that one](http://askubuntu.com/a/313119/22949), since you're saying that *just* removing the cache is sometimes sufficient. (I agree.) As another difference, you're *not* telling people to do it as root, with sudo. (I agree with you about that, too.) But this could be an even better answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing it completely and installing it again:

***Uninstall Software Center:***

`sudo apt-get remove software-center`

`sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`

(IMPORTANT)Remember to remove the cache

`~/.cache && rm -r software-center`

***Reinstall Software Center:***

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

It does look like it need to be updated and this should occur during installation.

Comment: Removing the cache shouldn't have to be done as root, though if people have run the Software Center in weird ways (e.g., `sudo software-center`--not recommended), it might be necessary. Recursive removals are scary when run as root. But then, they're scary otherwise, too. If someone accidentally puts a space (or presses enter) after the `~` or the first `/` in `rm -r ~/.cache/software-center` (with or without `sudo`), it deletes their entire home folder, including all their documents! (And this does happen.) Therefore, `cd ~/.cache && rm -r software-center` might be considered preferable.

Comment: Good catch. I have edited my post accordingly.